# What are the minimal permissions required to use a Vertex AI Workbench

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I would like to limit the permissions of the service account that is used inside a Vertex AI workbench. I know that I can choose a custom service account instead of the default compute service account when creating the workbench. But the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting-workbench?_gl=1*s8tgy*_ga*MTM4NTA2NTc2LjE1OTQ4MjkzNDQ.*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTY3MzAxMTM0MC4yNTguMS4xNjczMDExMzQzLjAuMC4w&_ga=2.228124637.-138506576.1594829344#creating_instances) says that whichever account I use that account needs to have the Editor role. I need to set up some workbenches for my colleagues but I don't want to give them Editor rights on the project (which they would effectively have since they would act as the service account when using the workbench). If I remove the Editor role from the service account the workbench won't start. What are the minimal permissions that the service account must have so that another user can start and use the workbench?

Comment: Hi @Martin Wiebusch, To create notebooks in Vertex AI workbench, service account needs to have the editor role.
These are the [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/iam#iam_roles) to access to the use of Vertex AI Workbench.